# Is there any way of retrieving all records from a data extension via REST API for Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, dataextensions, contact

I want to retrieve all contacts from a specific data extension via REST API but I don't find any documentation to do that.

Is there any way of retrieving all records from a data extension via REST API for Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an undocumented endpoint for getting records from a Data Extension using REST, with a filter defined by request parameters to the endpoint:

```
GET /data/v1/customobjectdata/key/YOURDEEXTERNALKEY/rowset?$filter=emailAddress%20eq%20'test@example.com' HTTP/1.1
Host: YOURTENANT.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer YOURAUTHTOKEN
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.17.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: YOURTENANT.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache
```

This is provided with NO GUARANTEES, and can be taken down or altered by Salesforce without any notice. I will not recommend using undocumented features in production context.

As to your question:

> I want to retrieve all contacts from a specific data extension

This is doomed to fail, as you potentially don't have any control of the number of records in a given data extension. Remember that your API request might time-out, or return such a huge amount of data, that generating a response will not be feasible. I will advise against a solution which relies on pulling ALL records from a data extension. You would be better off (while building a more robust solution) using [Data Extension Extract](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_extension_extract.htm&type=5) in Automation Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Data extension record retrieval via REST is now supported as part of 2024 spring release!  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_2024_spring_as_rest_api_endpoints.htm&type=5

Rest route Documentation
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc-custom_object_data?meta=Get%2Bcustom%2Bobject%2Bdata%2Bby%2Bkey

Great news not having to implement SOAP for such a common task/pattern

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.