# Using REST API to fetch data from SFMC Data View

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, data-views

I have seen various answers by Lukas Lunow ([Is there any way of retrieving all records from a data extension via REST API for Marketing Cloud?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/327463/is-there-any-way-of-retrieving-all-records-from-a-data-extension-via-rest-api-fo)) and Gortonington  on the usage of undocumented REST API to fetch data from a DE.

Is there any similar option to fetch data from a Data View (e.g. _Subscribers, _SMSMEssageTRacking, etc.) using query parameters for filter and pagination which work well for DEs? Can the same APIs be used and how do we obtain the ID or Key for a DataView?

I am referring to these 2 APIs

```
   "getCustomObjectDataById": {
        "path": "customobjectdata/{id}/rowset",
        "httpMethod": "get",
        "description": "Retrieves Data Extension data from Custom Object looked up by id",
        "parameters": {}
    },
    "getCustomObjectDataByKey": {
        "path": "customobjectdata/key/{key}/rowset",
        "httpMethod": "get",
        "description": "Retrieves Data Extension data from Custom Object looked up by key",
        "parameters": {}
    },
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried the REST-API (ByKey) for DE and it works very well. But cant use it for DVs. Tried using the DV name as ID in the ById API and get response "Parameter {id} is invalid."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot access the DataViews from REST API (at least not that I have found so far).

You can though hit the **[SOAP Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/soap_web_service_objects.html)** which hold very similar (almost identical) data.

- BounceEvent
- ClickEvent
- SentEvent
- OpenEvent
- Automation
- AutomationInstance
- ...etc

You can use these SOAP objects to do what you are looking to do with Pagination, filtering, etc.  Some of these objects do have limitations on filtering and what can be retrieved though, so you may want to research the capabilities of each before attempting the call.

Zuzanna has a **[great article](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/09/retrieve-tracking-data-since-account-inception-using-wsproxy/)** that you can use as a starting point for this.

Comment: Thank you . All of our API development is REST based

Comment: Then you’ll have to use sql to make a copy of data views and store this data in a regular de and fetch it from there